# NoClassDefFoundError on older android devices for using FingerprintManager

Tags: codenameone

I'm testing on older android device and I see the following message in the logs.  Login will take indefinite time. How can I avoid this situation and catching this exception doesn't solve the problem in anyway.

```
[main] 0:0:0,858 - This exception could be 100% valid on old devices, we're logging it just to be safe. Older devices might throw NoClassDefFoundError...
 [main] 0:0:1,22 - Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager
        at com.codename1.h.a.e$1.run(InternalFingerprintImpl.java:23)
        at com.codename1.impl.android.c$8.run(AndroidImplementation.java:4710)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I see this exception has been added in the recent update to the library.
https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner/commit/7c7e039b6487b19d882652b46ae9cb212f3b055b

Comment: This is a part of the fingerprint scanner API. That's an API that requires newer devices. You can limit your app to only run on newer devices or avoid using that specific library

Comment: limiting the devices on the playstore or is there a way we can do it in the code?

Comment: You can define this in the build hint `android.min_sdk_version` https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html